# How to Export top-level Classes into Jar?

Tags: java, jar

Hi all I was wondering if there is anyway to export top level classes (which means classes not in packages) into a jar file and call it from other Java projects?

Comment: You ought to have packages....this is not advisable.  Tomcat, for one, requires them.

Comment: Why would you ever want to not use packages?

Comment: Why are you having problems? .class files at the top of a jar file are classes in the default package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot import default-package classes; it is a compile-time error. ([JLS 7.5, Import Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5))

If the referencing class is in the default package, you don't need an import. Otherwise, I guess reflection.